# how to remove all Toggle BreakPoint once time?

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

I am a new Titanium User, I don't know about Toggle Breakepoint in Titanium, i set a lots or break point in one or many .js file. 
how, i remove all toggle view once time.

plz, help me?
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is Easy, 
when u use the Toggle BreakPoint, than, one bullet symbols show in left side.

You went on Run-> and select Remove All Breakpoint 
Run-->Remove All BreakPoint

Try This,

Answer (score 1):

In Run menu you have many options like Toggle Break Point, Toggle Line
 Break Point, Skip All Break Point etc u can use Toggle All break Point
 to Toggle all the break points or Remove All BreakPoints To remove all
 Break Points, Hope this will hel